# How to make my home server accessible using server's IP address?

Tags: networking, router, firewall, windows-server-2019

I have an home server that I build using Windows Server 2019. Everyone on my network can connect to it using the //*servername*/*dir* in file explorer, but everyone outside my network aren't able to connect using my Public IP address.

I would like to say that that I am a beginner at all of this. Sorry to anyone who has to read this rubbish.

I have enabled port 80 in "Outbound Rules" on the server's firewall settings and also opened that port under port forwarding options within my Xfinity Router.

The port is opened under "HTTP" service with both TCP/UDP and using my server's IPv4 address. Also the IPv6 is filled in.

How can I make this accessible to anyone outside my network provided that they have the right credentials logging in? For example using //*IP to server*/*dir* in File Explorer?

Comment: I think you need to mess with *inbound* rules instead. Also it's unclear what you are trying to expose. `//server/dir` doesn't sound like it is an http server you are trying to expose.

Comment: For example, what if you wanted to connect to my server and access the files on it?

Comment: It seems like you are trying to expose the SMB/CIFS server. Apparently it uses TCP port 445 these days.

Comment: Do I enable TCP port 445 under my router aswell as the server's firewall settings?

Comment: Most likely you set up port forwarding for it on the router (to your server) and allow inbound traffics for it on the server (assuming the firewall doesn't block any outbound traffics).

Comment: Will this let me access my server using //192.xxxxxx/dir ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102703/discussion-between-360codeyoutodeath-and-tom-yan).

Comment: Warning: exposing your server to the Internet opens you up to attack by pretty much everyone. Your server *will* be found and probed for vulnerabilities, including unpatched software, insecure setting, bad passwords, etc. Make sure your security is up to snuff before opening it up like this. And just in case, make sure you have a good backup system for anything that matters (though actually you should have that anyway).